# How do I implement my own selectedId for redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux to fetch some data using this api `"https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents"`. The problem is I cannot show all the agents and only 1 showing up and I got warning from redux says:

> the entity passed from selectId returned undefined, you should
> probably implement your own selectId function

[image: warning from redux]

I think there is mistake in my `valorantSlice`.

I try to show the list of agents like this

(in this api I want to show the details too)

```js
export const fetchValorants = createAsyncThunk(
  "valorants/fetchValorants",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents")
      .then((response) => response.data.data)
      .then((agents) => {
        return Promise.all(
          agents.map((agent: any) =>
            axios.get(`https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents/${agent.uuid}`)
          )
        );
      })
      .then((agentDetails) => {
        return agentDetails.map((response) => response.data.data);
      });

    return response;
  }
);
```

Here is my slice

```js
const valorantAdapter = createEntityAdapter();

const initialState = valorantAdapter.getInitialState({
  status: "idle",
  error: "" as any,
});

export const fetchValorants = createAsyncThunk(
  "valorants/fetchValorants",
  async () => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents")
      .then((response) => response.data.data)
      .then((agents) => {
        return Promise.all(
          agents.map((agent: any) =>
            axios.get(`https://valorant-api.com/v1/agents/${agent.uuid}`)
          )
        );
      })
      .then((agentDetails) => {
        return agentDetails.map((response) => response.data.data);
      });

    return response;
  }
);

const valorantsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "valorants",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchValorants.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(fetchValorants.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "succeeded";
        action.payload.forEach((agent) => {
          valorantAdapter.addOne(state, agent);
        });
      })
      .addCase(fetchValorants.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      });
  },
});

export default valorantsSlice.reducer;
export const {
  selectAll: selectAllValorants,
  selectById: selectValorantByUuid,
  selectIds: selectValorantUuids,
} = valorantAdapter.getSelectors((state: any) => state.valorants) as any;
```

I use react-redux in nextjs 13

redux devtools screenshot
[image: redux devtools screenshot]

Comment: Hi, can you also provide a screenshot of your Redux Devtools with that state after the `fetchValorants` thunk is fulfilled please.

Comment: my apologize because i still dont understand redux, i already add the screenshot

Comment: No problem don't worry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined under the entity key make me think response from Valorant API don't possess any ID.
(EDIT : with additional screenshot, theory seems validated :))

By default the entityAdapter of RTK will look for an id.

Based on the code of the thunk it seems that there is an `uuid` instead.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter#selectid

So you can pass a `selectId` to `createEntityAdapter` which will target the `uuid` key.

```js
const valorantAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (valorant) => valorant.uuid,
})
```

Comment: you save me, thank you for the answer. my app is fixed now.
so redux doesn't support any other than id? 
`const valorantAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (valorant: ValorantData) => valorant.uuid as string,
});`
i fix the app with this code

Comment: You're welcome. It's not Redux itself, it's RTK which has the will to automate some task in Redux and assume by default that entities contain an id key in order to manipulate data. So we need to give RTK a unique key if the `id` key doesn't exits :)